# garbage collector for JFrame's object

Tags: java, swing, garbage-collection, jframe

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main
{
    public Main()
    {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Demo");
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setSize(100, 100);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Main();
            }
        });
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

    }

}
```

I call `Runtime.getRuntime().gc();` for explicit garbage collector invoking. But window doesn't dissapear from screen, why doesn't garbage collector reclaim JFrame's object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a `JFrame` is created, it registers itself in some internal Swing data structures which allow it to receive events like mouse clicks. This means there is a reference to your object lurking somewhere until you tell Swing to get rid of the window using `dispose()`.

Answer (score 5):

Given the `invokeLater()` call, the call to GC will probably occur 1st<sup>1</sup>.

BTW - calling `Runtime.gc()` is generally pointless, the JRE won't GC till it needs to.

1. E.G.

#### Output

```
GC called
Frame visible
```

#### Code

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class VisibleFrameGC {

    VisibleFrameGC() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Demo");
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setSize(100, 100);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Frame visible");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new VisibleFrameGC();
            }
        });
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        System.out.println("GC called");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The frame is visible and the reference to the object is reachable by at least one of the GUI threads (the Event Dispatch Thread). That is why it isn't garbage collected.

---

If you want it to disapear, use [`frame.dispose()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29).